# API Manager and Medition for business services

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am looking for an easy way to mediate a set of technical APIs published on WSO2 AM in order to create super api (functional api).
Reading the documentation the mediation is in charge to WSO2 ESB the questions are:
-can we use other esb?
-which are the benefits to use the medition provided by WSO2 ESB?
-is there an internal mediation engine in the APi Manager for orchestrating api published on it?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
can we use other esb?
```

We use ESB as our gateway node, with some specific handlers. If you want to use separate WSO2ESB instance as gateway, you need to install APIManager's gateway features in it.

```
is there an internal mediation engine in the APi Manager for orchestrating api published on it
```

Yes. We use ESB for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the ESB for this purpose.This link, http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Features explains the features of WSO2ESB. 
API Manager has its own mediation engine and you can simply write a mediator and include in the extension sequence. For more details, http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension

Comment: Yes I read documentation about the internal mediation but it isn't clear how can I orchestrate api already published on it. Do you have an example of it?